# Cannot found the AWS EC2 storage disks I created

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created two virtual disks for AWS EC2. One is 16G and the other is 100G.

[image: AWS EC2 storage]

When I connect to EC2 with puTTy it does not show the disks that I created.

[image: puTTy SSH]

Anyone know what the problem is or how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: That command is the output of `df`, which only shows mounted filesystems. You have to format the volume and mount it before it will show up in `df`. The `lsblk` command will show available drives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Make an Amazon EBS volume available for use on Linux](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html)

> After you attach an Amazon EBS volume to your instance, it is exposed as a block device. You can format the volume with any file system and then mount it. After you make the EBS volume available for use, you can access it in the same ways that you access any other volume. Any data written to this file system is written to the EBS volume and is transparent to applications using the device.

Depending on your requirement you can choose two ways:

- Format and mount an attached volume
- Automatically mount an
  attached volume after reboot